# How do I get TAnimate's Common AVIs to work on Vista and Win7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a Delphi 2007 application that has a TAnimate control with a FindFile Common AVI. It works perfectly when the application is run on Windows XP, but nothing ever appears on Windows 7. I've heard it now requires its own thread, but I am not certain.

Does anyone know how to get TAnimate's Common AVI control to work on Windows 7 (or Vista)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must add the unit ShellAnimations to you project or add the component [TShellResources](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/36211)  from the Win32 tab of the component palette. (Tested in Windows Vista- Delphi 2007)

```
uses
ShellAnimations;
```

this unit adds the following replacement animation resources to your executable:

- FindFolder.res
- FindFile.res
- FindComputer.res
- CopyFiles.res
- CopyFile.res
- RecycleFile.res
- EmptyRecycle.res
- DeleteFile.res

Bye.

Comment: Thank you. My animations stopped with Vista, and this fixed it for me as well. +1 for Q & A

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 7 it does not work. I use Windows 11 and I cannot load AVI to component. I get error always.